# neoj4 vs "traditional" RDBMS & Memcache / Messaging / Redis solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rabbitmq, neo4j, feed

I'm in the middle of prototyping a social network (using ROR 3) and decided to check out Neo4j and while it looks great, I have a question about scaling and performance in terms of design.

I've researched how Etsy puts together and activity feed (see http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture ), and understand how messaging queues can fan out activities (such as sharing a picture and making this activity available to your 500 or so friends in their news feed).  I also understand how news feeds can be cached (memcache) and how lookups can be performed against Redis..

All in all, it seems that to make a high performance activity feed that scales well (and social network in general) the common pattern is to use sharding, horizontal scaling, memcache, rabbitmq, redis, Mongodb, innodb (mysql) etc - all in attempt to compensate for high volumes, disk reads, etc..  **But this is quite a bit of overhead in terms of design**..

**Can Neo4J eliminate the need, at least early on, for such an arrangement**? I mean is it so fast that I don't need to set a message queue for fan outs and messaging, don't need to set up "activities" cache for every action a user performs, and can use it to handle both ordering and storing messaging?  Can a news feed like Facebook's be created with such a system, or is the high performance activity feed limited to basic status updates?

If those questions are too broad, let me ask it a different way: Could I write facebook or twitter using neo4j and eliminate the need for message queuing to fan out updates (instead I want to get a live stream of updates on the fly), memcache for newsfeeds, and cached activity feed objects?  Or will I find myself doing the same thing or even more to handle hundreds of request per second?

I ask the because it would save quite a bit of time to use Neo4J if it can indeed handle high volumes without having to use the tricks Etsy, Twitter, and Facebook employ to maintain high performance.

Comment: Early on, the short answer to this question is yes. Remember, it doesn't make sense to solve a problem that you don't have. The problem that you have is that you don't have a prototype. Adding a bunch of optimisation to a prototype that isn't there doesn't make a lot of sense, if you use Neo4J correctly (I.E., use the Server rather than embedded version) then you can easily optimise over time *as needed*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I can appreciate not coding for a problem until one has it, but on the other hand why wait when it's well known what problems commonly arise?   I do have a prototype using Active Record, just not an activity feed (messaging is already done, photo uploading, etc done.. just not the news feed etc)..  The last thing a startup needs is a hiccup which could have been avoided with just a bit more work.. I'd love to just get a system working and worry about optimization later - but being unfunded - don't have $ or time to hire more help to deal with optimizations later..

Comment: Thanks for the tip on server vs embedded..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, it's been done already by Rene Pickhardt.

http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/

Comment: Great answer.. I saw this... was hoping for something simpler to read / digest before deciding to make the leap from mysql to neo4j..

Comment: Max..maybe this would interest you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645938/neo4j-linked-list-multiple-nodes