# Converting a star-topology to a linked list in Neo4j

Tags: linked-list, neo4j, cypher

When I initially created my data set I thought a star topology would be nice, but now that I've gotten some sample data, I'd rather be using a [linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645938/neo4j-linked-list-multiple-nodes) topology. Now I want to do an in-place conversion using Cypher only, and in one call. Is this possible?

To use a simplified example: a `Blog` node can have several children `Post` nodes, so I attached them directly like this:

```
CREATE (a:Blog), (a)-[:HAS]->(b:Post), (a)-[:HAS]->(c:Post)
RETURN a,b,c
```

Now as my design moves along, I think I'd rather have this as a linked list, something like this (assuming the `:FIRST` post is already created):

```
MATCH (a:Blog)-[r:FIRST]->(b:Post)
CREATE (a)-[:FIRST]->(c:Post)-[:PREV]->(b)
DELETE r
RETURN a,b,c
```

So I can code the linked list fine. What I need to do is to convert the old star topologies to the new linked list format. I tried a bunch of things but nothing worked, so here is my best guess, but is completely non-functional code:

```
MATCH (b:Blog)-[:HAS]-(p:Post)
WITH b, collect(p) as posts
CREATE b-[:FIRST]->posts[0]
FOREACH( i IN range(1,len(posts)-1) |
    CREATE posts[i]-[:PREV]->posts[i-1]
)
RETURN b,p
```

Indexing collections doesn't seem to work in a `CREATE` statement (neither inside or outside the `FOREACH`).

Any way to achieve this translation?

**EDIT**
I thought an additional way might be to tag the posts with ordinal values and do some iteration over sequential ordinals, but I get a syntax error trying to add the ordinals:

```
MATCH (b:Blog)-[:HAS]-(p:Post)
WITH b, collect(p) as posts
FOREACH( i in range(0,length(posts)) |
    SET posts[i].ordinal = i
}
```

The syntax error is:

```
Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, a relationship pattern, '(', '.' or '=' (line 4, column 14)
"    SET posts[i].ordinal = i"
              ^
```

**EDIT/2**

Another idea I had was to put the linked-list code inside the `FOREACH`, but this fails because `MATCH` cannot be used inside `FOREACH`. First I created and attached a dummy `(b:Blog)-[:FIRST]->(p:Post)` relationship, then wrote this query (which doesn't work):

```
MATCH (f)<-[:FIRST]-(b:Blog)-[:HAS]->(p:Post)
WITH b, collect(p) as posts
FOREACH( x IN posts |
    MATCH (b)-[r:FIRST]->(f) 
    DELETE r
    CREATE (b)-[r2:FIRST]->(x), (x)-[:PREV]->(f)
)
RETURN b-[*0..1]-()
```

Comment: how do you maintain the sequence of the time when the post nodes are added to the blog? Are all blog to post relations in your star topology are of HAS type?

Comment: At this point I'm not concerned at all with the ordering, as I can't even get the query to work without it. But it's a totally valid point once I get a query that works. In my scenario the `Post` nodes all have timestamps set like so: `CREATE (p:Post { created:timestamp() })`

Comment: what are the other properties inside Post node?

Comment: The other properties aren't important. This is a [minimal, complete, and tested](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of my problem, and is enough to reproduce my scenario. `Blog` and `Post` are only placeholders in the minimal scenario used to illustrate the problem. You can add whatever field(s) you think are necessary to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a crutch until you find a better workarund you could try nesting `FOREACH (a IN [posts[i]] | FOREACH (b IN [posts[i-1]] | CREATE a-[:PREV]->b))` inside your original foreach loop, as a way to unpack the index slices. For edit 1 try `SET (posts[i]).ordinal = i`. I think I have a nicer workaround somewhere but can't remember at the moment, if I find it I'll put it up.

Comment: Nice! This works great. It wasn't clear to me from any of the documentation (and I've read it *all*) that I could index into collections, and the syntax needed is context dependent. Like you've shown here, when referencing the properties of an collection indexer, you need to wrap the index in parentheses: `(coll[i]).blah`. But this doesn't work in a relationship pattern. I.e. `CREATE (posts[i])-[:LINK]->(posts[i-1])` throws an `InvaldSyntax` error. Unpacking with nested `FOREACH` is a nice workaround, and works perfectly.

Comment: p.s. I'd like to wait to accept this as the answer to see what other work-arounds might exist, or until I figure one out based on this information. I like this and it works perfectly, I'd just like to see if there's something more elegant (like you mentioned you might have lying around somewhere). This will definitely get me through the day though! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this Cypher Query

**After Edit**

```
MATCH (a:Blog)-[r:HAS]->(p:Post)
WITH a,r,collect(p) as posts,range(1,length(posts)) as rel
MERGE(firstPost:Post {created: head(posts).created , otherprop: head(posts).otherprop})
CREATE a-[:FIRST]->(firstPost)
FOREACH(i IN rel | 
MERGE(thisPost:Post {created: (posts[i]).created , otherprop: (posts[i]).otherprop})
MERGE(prevPost:Post {created: (posts[i-1]).created , otherprop: (posts[i-1]).otherprop})
CREATE (prevPost)-[:NEXT]->(thisPost))
WITH a
MATCH a-[r:HAS]->() delete r
```

This will create something like (Blog)-[FIRST]->(Post)-[NEXT]->(Post)...
By default Cypher sorts the element in `COLLECT(p)` in natural ascending order. Hence if you have only created property it will sort in the most recent one at last, hence the last node in the next chain starting from `BLOG` will be your latest `POST` associated to that `BLOG`

Comment: Where is the reference on this `i-1` syntax? I'm using Neo4j Community v2.0.0, and am getting a syntax error with this code listing, pointing to the `1` in `i-1`: `Type mismatch: expected Map but was Long (line 7, column 32)
"    MERGE(prevPost:Post {id: i-1.id })"`. Also, I tried some simpler examples and they likewise complained that `i-1` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Exception: `Expected a numeric value for RangeFunction(Literal(1),LengthFunction(Property(p,array)),Literal(1)), but got null`. Does this code compile for you? Simplifying this down to `MATCH (p:Post) RETURN p.array` returns three rows containing `null`. `p.array` is trying to access the `array` property of the `:Post` node, which doesn't exist. If this code works for you, could you point me to some references on where you found `<collection>.array` should convert the collection to an array? Likewise, `length(p.array)` is `length(null)` which is where the current exception is coming from.

Comment: check now. The previous I tried on some other online sample graph which had array prop . sorry about that. collect() by itself returns an array.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but posting non-working code is really frustrating, especially if it was for another graph. I spent time debugging code that you posted that didn't compile. Frustrating especially since I'm struggling with my own bugs. @jjarderberg beat you to working code (notably wrapping the indexer in parentheses, and the `FOREACH` unpacking), so I'm going to pursue his answer. Also, I don't believe the `MERGE` is necessary or appropriate here since I'd have to know every property on the node apriori, and all I'm trying to do is create a relationship *between* **existing** nodes.